# how to perform two operations on the same flux

Tags: project-reactor, flux

I have a project reactor Flux. I want to perform two different operation on the same flux. I thought of doing the below way. But this is happening in sequential way. Is there any better way I can get this two operation to happen in parallel as they are independent operations

```
myFlux.reduce(this::operationOne).subscribe(System.out::println);
myFlux.reduce(this::operationTwo).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @Felipe: no, that answer is mostly talking about parallel execution. Still it will do one operation only. My ask is for doing two different operation on same flux in parallel

Comment: I think what you need is a `ConnectableFlux`: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-broadcast-multiple-subscribers-connectableflux Also, you might want to look into `publishOn` operator which lets you offload the work to a separate thread.